# Correct CSS / JS parameters to fill div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a slideshow that I would like to fill a div completely. 
Right now, if someone visits my site from a narrow browser viewport, the slideshow will only fill the width but not the entire height, therefore leaving space at the bottom of the div.

I would like the slideshow to **proportionally scale to fit and cover the entire div, even if cropping from the sides is necessary**. Does this make sense what I am asking?

Here's the example:
If you visit it right now from a wide or full screen browser window, the images probably fill the entire div.   **But if you narrow your window and refresh, you will see the bg color at the bottom of the div.** Example:
http://mudchallenger.com/a-responsivef.html

How can I get this slideshow to fill the div?

Thank you!!

Comment: What have you tried? We are not here to write your web site for you. Besides the question feels like you are fishing for visitors

Comment: I'm not asking anyone to write anything. I'm trying to figure out how to get a my slideshow to fill the div.

I have tried several things (more of testing to see if things work) using css to fill the div in the second link I provided.

It works for a div bg image, but I don't know how to use it with the sideshow. Or perhaps this isn't even going to work at all.

I used this for the css bg image
background: url(a-images/backgrounds/background3.jpg)no-repeat center center; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: @EdHeal ... I have no interest in fishing for visitors. I just asked a question and the best way to present my problem is to provide a link.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably change your **position:absolute** for **slideshow** class

```
.slideshow  {
     position: absolute;
 }
```

Comment: Hey @Sunny, thank's for the suggestion. Still didn't really do anything I don't think.  When I visit from a narrow window (like 1000px wide)  the slideshow image no longer fills the div vertically.

Thank you for helping though!  Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a way to make your background image fit the back of the page. What Ed is looking for is the CSS/JS that you currently have, so we can better tell you what you should do differently.

This article gives great examples of different ways of achieving what you're asking for:

[Perfect Full Page Backgrounds](http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

And if you're interested in another way, here's a JS library that does it as well.

[Backstretch](http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/)

Without seeing your code, that's as good an answer as can be given.

Comment: Actually, I'm trying to get the background slideshow images to fill the div only, not the page.

Perhaps this link will give help me explain better... The slideshow at the top, I want it to fill the div. If the browser is too narrow, you will see green at the bottom of the div.
http://mudchallenger.com/a-responsiveb.html