# CSS Layering Divs

Tags: css

I want 100% wide divs containing images to go down my page. 
On top of these divs, I want one 1210px wide div where I can put my content.

Example:
http://mudchallenger.com/a-responsivee.html

Question:
How can I get the blue box to touch the green box, while red box stays above the two?

Thank you!

I currently have this:

```
}
#green{
position: absolute;
float:center;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:1;
background-color: green;
}
#blue{
position: relative;
float:center;
height: 500px;
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:1;
background-color: blue;
}
#red{
position: relative;
float:center;
height: 800px;
width: 1210px;
margin: 0 auto;
z-index:2;
background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Sounds like what you're really looking for is a background-image...

Comment: @Malcoda - Well in a way, yes. Multiple backgrounds that span horizontally. I actually want my page to look like this...
http://mudchallenger.com/a-responsivec.html

But for some reason, my css is all jacked up on ipad viewing. Looks good on the desktop, but I need to wrap everything in a container and put it on top of those horizontal divs.  Any suggestions?

Comment: My guess is that page simply uses a background image on container divs going down the screen and then puts the content within those container divs. The content doesn't cover the entire container div giving it the desired look.

Comment: Thank you. But to answer my question, how would one make the boxes touch? haha... I'm missing something here, i'm sure... @Malcoda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use background-images to accomplish what you want. Just stack your divs and it should work just fine. If you want your content to span two containers with background images, that's a different story, but the example you cite doesn't do that.

Here's a fiddle giving close to an implementation of what you want. Just replace the container background-colors with background-images and you'd have what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/CfZu4/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
    Blah
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container red">
    <div class="content">
    Blah
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container{
background-color:#00f;
height:200px;
clear:both;
}
.content{
float:right;
width:40%;
height:150px;
margin-top:20px;
background-color:#0f0;
}
.red{
background-color:#f00;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help!  That one one of my two problems.   My second problem I posted last night, but didn't get much help. Could you take a look at it?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24298404/correct-css-js-parameters-to-fill-div

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: Scaled down version for fiddle:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dc2bar/asy8Y/2/

HTML:

```
<div class="background-banner green">
    <div class="main-content red">
        <!-- content -->
    </div>
</div>
<div class="background-banner blue">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.background-banner {
    height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:1;
}

.main-content {
    position: relative;
    height: 800px;
    width: 70%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    z-index:2;
}

.green{
    background-color: green;
}

.blue{
    background-color: blue;
}

.red{
    background-color: red;
}
```

EDIT yet again: removed invalid css rule.

Comment: There is no such thing as float: center;

Comment: true, sorry i used OP's css and simply moved things around.